# How to make a chat program server send message to all connected clients in java

Tags: java, networking, tcp, chat

I have tried to make this program three times each time getting a little further. My program should work like this:

A client sends a message to the server which then sends the message to all connected clients (including the client that sent the message). When the clients receive the message they display it.

The problem I'm facing right now is that the server sends the message only to the client that sent it while the other clients receive nothing. I think this is happening because of the way I accept clients or at least it's somehow related to this

Here is my current code:

Client:

```
public class Client {

    protected static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 30);
    protected static String sendMSG, getMSG;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String hostName = args[0];
        String Username = args[1];
        boolean sending = true;

        try (
            Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, 1011);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            //frame setup
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("chat client");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //text area
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

            //text field
            JTextField MSGText = new JTextField(5);

            //"send" button
            JButton sMSGB = new JButton("send");
            sMSGB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
            sMSGB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    sendMSG = MSGText.getText();
                    MSGText.setText("");
                    out.println("<" + Username + ">: " + sendMSG);
                }

            });

            //panel
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout((new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)));
            p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
            p.add(scrollPane);
            p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
            p.add(MSGText);
            p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
            p.add(sMSGB);
            p.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
            frame.getContentPane().add(p);

            //set frame visible
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            System.out.println("<Client>: opened stream");

            while(sending) {

                /*while((sendMSG = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.println("<" + Username + ">: " + sendMSG);
                }*/

                while((getMSG = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(getMSG);
                    textArea.append(getMSG + "\n");
                    //sending = false;
                }
            }
            //sending = true;
        } 
    }       
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1011)) {
            boolean listening = true;
            while(listening) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                List<PrintWriter> outs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<PrintWriter>();
                new ServerThread(socket, outs).start();
                System.out.println("opened thread");
            }

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerThread:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private final Socket socket;
    private final List<PrintWriter> outs;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket, List<PrintWriter> outs) {
        super("ServerThread");
        this.socket  = socket;
        this.outs = outs;
        System.out.println("Opened outs: " + outs.size());
    }

    private void sendToAll(String msg) {
        for(PrintWriter out: outs) {
            out.println(msg);
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            System.out.println("stream opened");
            outs.add(out);
            String getMSGs;

            while((getMSGs = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //out.println(getMSGs);
                sendToAll(getMSGs);
                System.out.println("msg received and sent");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're reinitializing `outs` every time new client connects:

```
            while(listening) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                List<PrintWriter> outs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<PrintWriter>();
                new ServerThread(socket, outs).start();
                System.out.println("opened thread");
            }
```

and basically spawning threads  with empty `outs`. You need to keep the list of output streams (or sockets) outside the loop and build a way to signal already existing threads when you update the `outs` list (when a new client connects).